# Error - Corresponding column type must be compatible - DateTime field - Entity Framework, Informix, Load multiple childs

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datetime, informix, children

Environment:
Entity Framework 5.0 for .Net 4.0
Informix (IDS)
IBM Data Server Client 9.7

I am trying to retrieve more than one child tables data using LINQ to entities:
Ex:-
var res = dbContext.Commercial_Invoice.Include(x=>x.Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item).Include(y=>y.Cmrcl_Invc_Contact);

Here is entity framework generated database query (other columns are omitted for simplicity):-

```
(SELECT 
    Extent1.cmrcl_invc_id AS cmrcl_invc_id  
   ,Extent2.last_change_ts AS last_change_ts1      
   FROM  "informix".Commercial_Invoice AS Extent1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "informix".Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item AS Extent2 ON Extent1.cmrcl_invc_id = Extent2.cmrcl_invc_id
   WHERE CAST(366 AS int) = Extent1.cmrcl_invc_id)
UNION ALL
   (SELECT       
   Extent3.cmrcl_invc_id AS cmrcl_invc_id
,CAST(NULL AS datetime year to fraction(5)) AS C21 
   FROM  "informix".Commercial_Invoice AS Extent3
   INNER JOIN "informix".Cmrcl_Invc_Contact AS Extent4 ON Extent3.cmrcl_invc_id = Extent4.cmrcl_invc_id
   WHERE CAST(366 AS int) = Extent3.cmrcl_invc_id);
```

While executing this query I am getting "Corresponding column types must be compatible for each UNION statement".
When I change the query : CAST(NULL AS datetime year to fraction(5)) to CAST(NULL AS datetime year to second), executed without error.

In Database last_change_ts column type is DateTime.

It seems Entity Framework using "year to fraction(5)" for casting by default.

Any ideas/suggestions to solve this.

Thanks in advance,
Phani

Comment: And what Linq did you use to generate this?

Comment: @DavidG  querying using "Include".  Context.Commercial_Invoice.Include(x=>x.Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item).Include(y=>y.Cmrcl_Invc_Contact)

Comment: "Date fields" - which date fields? "Year" - what year? "Change to year to second" - what do you mean? Seeing your previous questions, you really have a problem making others understand what you're talking about. Maybe it's about time you visit the Help Center, esp. [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you have questions about a LINQ statement it's shouldn't be hard to imagine that including this whole statement is the least thing to do.

Comment: @GertArnold  Thank you for suggestion.  I have changed problem details. Please check if it understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityFramework.IBM.DB2 6.0.2 
From release notes:
This patch (release) addresses the exception, "IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Exception: ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/UNIX32] Corresponding column types must be compatible for each UNION statement." , thrown while generating or updating an EDM targeting IBM Informix Dynamic Servers.
But it supports from DB2 Data Server Client 10.5 FP 5

Answer (score 0):

In your class definition for `Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item`, you can try manually specifying the database data type for the `last_change_ts` property using the [`Column` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute.aspx).  For example:

```csharp
[Column(TypeName="datetime year to second")]
public DateTime last_change_ts {get; set;}
```

That *should* change the type used in the generated query.

Comment: Thank you Matt Johnson. But it is throwing error -  "Schema specified is not valid. The type datetime year to second is not qualifies with a namespace or alias."

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have informix nor the libraries.  I'm sure that somewhere in that library's documentation there should be a list of valid data type names for the EF schema.  Usually they are identical to the type name in the db, but it's possible they are slightly different.  If you can provide a link to the specific informix libraries you are using, I can try test it out.  I searched, but there appear to be several different providers available.

Comment: Thank you Matt.       I am suing DB2 Data Server Client v 9.7. [link] (https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/pick.do?source=swg-idsc97&lang=en_US). I tried in documentation too, but didn't find much details on this.